# INFO[0015] [8] System error: pipe2: too many open files on docker build

Tags: build, docker, many-to-many

I'm trying to build a docker file but i got this:

> INFO[0015] [8] System error: pipe2: too many open files

docker info:

```
Containers: 7
 Images: 484
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:3-795388-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: 
 Metadata file: 
 Data Space Used: 19.21 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 88.16 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 26.91 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.121 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Library Version: 1.02.89-RHEL6 (2014-09-01)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 7.687 GiB
```

docker version:

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2/1.6.2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2/1.6.2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Any Idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all untagged images:

```
sudo docker images -a | grep '<none>' | awk '{print $3}' | xargs sudo docker rm
```

and restart the Docker itself:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: The last part must be `docker rmi`